# C++ virtual inheritance - override of virtual function "" is ambiguous

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a virtual inheritance example like below:

```
class Polygon {
public:
    virtual double area() = 0;
};

class Rectangle : public virtual Polygon {
    double a, b;
public:
    Rectangle(double a, double b) {
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;
    }
    double area() { return a * b; }
};

class Rombus : public virtual Polygon {
    double a, h;
public:
    Rombus(double a, double h) {
        this->a = a;
        this->h = h;
    }
    double area() { return a * h; }
};

class Square : public Rectangle, public Rombus {
public:
    Square(double a) : Rectangle(a, a), Rombus(a, a)  {}
};
```

It is one of requirements that Suare has to inherit from Rectangle and Rombus. That's why I use virtual inheritance.
But then I got an error:

```
override of virtual function "Polygon::area" is ambiguous
'Square': ambiguous inheritance of 'double Polygon::area(void)'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please tell me why are you using virtual inheritance for polygon?

Comment: Apart from the technical aspect of your question, which others already answered, this is flawed from a design perspective. The typical way to demonstrate this flaw is by the inheritance relation between circle and ellipse, which you should be able to find further info about easily. In short, neither is a base of the other, because neither supports the behaviour it would have to support by the "is a" relation to its baseclass.

Comment: Object-oriented design is useful to control behaviour, not to model data.

Answer (score 4):

The error message is:

> 'Square': ambiguous inheritance of 'double Polygon::area(void)'

It should be obvious why: there are two implementations!

```
double area() { return a * b; } // in Rectangle
double area() { return a * h; } // in Rhombus
```

`Square` inherits both of them, so there is no possible way the compiler could know which to use.

You can "fix" it by overriding `area()` in `Square` as well.

This design is deficient from the start: a `Square` should only contain a single member, its width/height.  But yours contains four members, all of which will always have the same value!